# ColdFusion 2018 connecting via secure ftp to remote server

Tags: java, coldfusion, sftp

We've been connecting to a remote sFTP server now for a couple years using the username and password they provided, as well as setting secure=true in the cfftp parameters.

They're now telling us that since we're connecting via an older algorithm (ssh-rsa) that we'll no longer be able to connect as they're disabling that in favor of rsa-sha2-256 or rsa-sha2-512.

The exact phrase they're using is:  *server_host_key_algorithm*

They have never sent us a key file, nor have they asked us to provide to them a public key file.  We've generated some keys but cfftp will only accept username + **password** + key OR username + key + **passphrase** (for the key file).

From my limited understanding, while you authenticate with username + keyfile, sftp can also authenticate with username + password and then use the keys for the tunnel.  However, some articles I've read say we give them our public key for the tunnel, others have said they should give us their private key, and others have said that no key file exchange between humans is necessary and that the server (them) will handle all of that.

If there's no keyfile exchange and this is just an algorithm, there doesn't seem to be any way to "set" CF to not use ssh-rsa.  Also, their message referencing *server_host_key_algorithm* seems like that's on them?  Which then leads to the question why am I getting automated emails saying that my username was connecting with a soon-to-be unsupported algorithm.

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated as their helpdesk that sent us these messages doesn't seem to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know ColdFusion. But as with any SSH/SFTP client – had it supported SHA2, it would use it automatically.

So I guess it does not support it. And there's most likely nothing you can do about it. Except for making sure you have the latest version.